# Skype for Business has a Meet Now Url that I can send to my attendees?

Tags: office365, skype, lync, skype-for-business

Back in the hey days (Live Meeting) there was a Meet Now Url that one could send to attendees so they can join the meeting.  I signed up for Skype for Business and I"m looking for that "Meet Now" Url but I can't find it.

I basically need a url to have my attendees join a video conferencing call.  I need to send it via email.  Anyone know where I can find that Url or construct one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside settings button, there is down arrow , click on it. You will find 'Meet now' option in that.Click on it, a dialog box will pop up namely 'Join Meeting Audio'.Select "Use Skype for business" radio button and click OK.
On bottom-right side, there will be an image, on hovering on it , you can read more options.Click on it,from list of options , select 'Meeting Entry Info'.
you can get the meeting  `url` from there.